# How to escape CMake generator inside CMakeLists.txt

Tags: android, cmake, escaping

I'm cross-compiling taglib for Android, and I've stumbled on an issue. I don't know how to escape the cmake `-G` parameter inside a CMakeLists.txt.

```
CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/taglib-${TAGLIB_VERSION}/.
                      -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android
                      -DCMAKE_ANDROID_API=${ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL}
                      -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=${ANDROID_ABI}
                      -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=${ANDROID_NDK}
                      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="${ANDROID_NDK}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake"
  How to escape? ->   -G"\"Unix Makefiles\""
                      -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=${ANDROID_NDK}/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make.exe
                      -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
                      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/taglib/install
```

`-G"\"Unix Makefiles\""`

How to escape this inside a CMakeLists.txt?

I'm getting CMake errors:

[image]

EDIT: Seems I escaped it, still does not work?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format works (escaping the space):

`-GUnix\ Makefiles`